# Powershell: variable date insertion into url strings

Tags: regex, powershell, parsing, url, wildcard

I need to dynamically alter the date part in various urls for webscraping purposes. Both the date and the formatting needs to be variable.

For instance today I might want to request:

> www.website.com/?startdate=2020-01-01&enddate=2020-01-02

Whereas tomorrow I might want:

> www.website.com/?startdate=2020-01-02&enddate=2020-01-03

My current solution is by passing the following format to my script as a parameter:

> www.website.com/?startdate=<-1,yyyy-MM-dd>&enddate=<0,yyyy-MM-dd>

Where the part left of the comma is the day I need, and the part to the right is its formatting.

I am using the following script to get my result:

```
$url = "www.website.com/?startdate=<-1,yyyy-MM-dd>&enddate=<0,yyyy-MM-dd>"

$urlsplit = $url.Split("<>") | Where-Object {$_}

Switch ($urlsplit.Length)
{
1 { 
    $result = $url 
}
2 { 
    $dayone = $urlsplit[1].Split(",")[0]
    $formatone =  $urlsplit[1].Split(",")[1] 
    $result = $urlsplit[0] + ((Get-Date).AddDays($dayone).ToString($formatone)) 
}
4 {
    $dayone = $urlsplit[1].Split(",")[0]
    $daytwo = $urlsplit[3].Split(",")[0]
    $formatone = $urlsplit[1].Split(",")[1]
    $formattwo = $urlsplit[3].Split(",")[1]
    $result = $urlsplit[0] + ((Get-Date).AddDays($dayone).ToString($formatone)) + $urlsplit[2] + ((Get-Date).AddDays($daytwo).ToString($formattwo))
}
}
Write-Output $result
```

Urls can contain no date, one date, or two (as above). This is why I currently need the switch statement.

Can this be done in a simpler manner?

Comment: Just pass what you're putting into .ToString() as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a custom function that will do what you seek in a simplified manner without all of those split.

**Usage**

```
Write-Host 'Start date only' -ForegroundColor Cyan
Get-Url -StartDate (get-date).AddDays(-1)
Write-Host 'Start date + End date' -ForegroundColor Cyan
Get-Url -StartDate (get-date).AddDays(-1) -EndDate (Get-Date)
Write-Host 'End date only' -ForegroundColor Cyan
Get-Url -EndDate (get-date).AddDays(10)
Write-Host 'No params' -ForegroundColor Cyan
Get-Url
```

I forgot to include in my screenshot but you can also specify a custom format using the corresponding `-Format` parameter.

```
Get-Url -StartDate (Get-Date) -Format 'yyyy\/MM\/dd'
Get-Url -StartDate (Get-Date) -Format 'yyyy-MM'
```

**Result**

[image: result]

**Function Definition**

```
Function Get-Url {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param (
        [datetime]$StartDate,  
        [datetime]$EndDate ,  
        $Format = 'yyyy-MM-dd'  
    )

    $Start, $End = ''
    $EndSymbol = '?'
    if ($StartDate -ne $null) {
        $Start = "?startdate=$($StartDate.ToString($Format))"
        $EndSymbol = '&'
    }

    if ($EndDate -ne $null) {
        $End = "($EndSymbol)EndDate=$($EndDate.ToString($Format))"
    }

    return "www.website.com/$Start$($End)"

}
```